# Multi domain redirect with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website that is referred by 2 urls.

http://firstdomain.com

http://seconddomain.com

I would like to redirect ALL the urls that point to http://seconddomain.com to /en (http://seconddomain.com/en). Is this possible? And how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?seconddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /en [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} seconddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en [L,R=301]
```